# How can I bevel the edges of a cylinder with multiple faces?

Tags: modeling, faces, bevel

I have a cylinder that I have used the Boolean Modifier to take out some shapes. This has caused multiple faces to be generated.

I have tried to reduce the amount of faces on a cylinder with dissolve faces and a few other options, but can't get to the point where I can bevel the edges of this cylinder easily.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: The shape in question]

Answer (score 6):

I would remodel it for better quad topology. There's a pretty nifty built-in addon called [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html). Enable it via menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools*

[image]

- Add a circle <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Mesh > Circle* with 32 vertices
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to [`Inset`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) a deep inner circle then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and scroll forward to add [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm
- Delete the other half of the geometry and fill in the half circle
- Then add a [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) on the X-axis
- You can easily shape the mouth by moving a few vertices
- Select the mouth area and press <kbd>i</kbd> to [`Inset Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) then <kbd>B</kbd> to turn off *Boundary* then <kbd>LMB</kbd>
- Select a sqaure area where you want the eye to be and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Loop Tools > Circle*
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> again to inset to add a nice [`Face Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html#select-face-loops) then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm
- Now you can select the [`Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html#select-edge-loops) of the mouth and eye and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to [`Bevel`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html)
- Optionally in *Object Mode*, <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Shade Smooth* and add [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html)

[image]

Now you have prettier topology and smoother bevels

[image]

If you tinker around you can also come up with prettier topology without ugly N-Gons by starting with quads from a Plane object and forming it into a circle then moving around vertices.

[image]

Comment: This looks great!
The only problem I have is when I press i to inset faces the second time — on this step: "Select the mouth area and press i to Inset Faces then B to turn off Boundary then LMB" The inset faces feature insets every individual face, not all of them together as it does in your gif. Is there a way to group them together that I'm missing?

Comment: Press 'i' again to alternate between individual and not. Or in the pop up window, uncheck the 'individual' option

Comment: @Cornivius This doesnt work, and I'm not sure why... Same with the pressing B

Comment: at the top while insetting you make sure you see if Boundary (OFF) and Individual (OFF) as seen in this screenshot https://snipboard.io/zOlFdG.jpg  you will see these values toggle whenever you press `B` or `I` or `O` for outset

Comment: Ror rigid bodies ngons on a flat surface are workable, you just need to divide them so they are convex (so that a straight line connecting any two points within the ngon will never go outside the ngon), then you inset those ngons to create a buffer of quads, and preferably inset again to have a double buffer of quads. Then Subdivision Surface + smooth shading won't be affected by ugly triangulation of ngons, and angle-limited bevel should leave ngons alone as well.

Comment: Boundary, Individual and Outset are indeed all OFF. Still no luck

Comment: @Lxxj are you sure you have no overlapping vertices? select all with `A` then press `M` then choose merge *By Distance*

Comment: Amazing yes this worked! Another question I have is how did you connect the central sides of the smile once you inset them?

Comment: @Lxxj great! you mean the center part of the smile? that's where the `B` (Boundary) comes into play. Once you press `i`, press `B` while you are still moving your mouse before you confirm your inset with left click. you will notice that continuously pressing B toggles it to make the inset stick to the side or not.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady [maybe like this better?](https://snipboard.io/jvGw0L.jpg) without ngons. i started with a plane and formed it into circle and moved around vertices. Lxxj > this is without using bevels. just subdivision.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie oh, quad based topo is definitely better, just saying ngons are often good enough :P. With ngons it can be tricky to do this double inset, whereas with quads the entire space is available for bevel/subdiv.